# Error al realizar una consulta a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

la función es realizada exitosamente pero al cargar el sitio siempre sale este error
`ERROR: error DB.`

```
No Se Puede Ejecutar La Consulta:
select * from tbl_documentos where tbl_documentos.cedula=
MySql Tipo De Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: cuando dices la funcion es realizada exitosamente, pero al cargar el sitio sale este error, a que te refieres ? a que la funcion se ejecuta correctamente en localhost, pero no en un servidor real ?, podrias especificar un poco más

Comment: a lo que me refiero es que la consulta es realizada pero mas no se a que se debe el error en mencion http://sistema.centrodesolucionsst.com/alumnos/listarporced.php

Comment: deberías editar la pregunta y adjunta el codigo de como haces la conexion, como es el codigo donde estas realizando la consulta a la base de datos y cuales son los parametros que le estas pasando

Answer (score 0):

Un par de consejos:

Trata de comprender lo que te devuelve MySQL, está claro lo que dice, si se te dificulta, usa el traductor, muchos los hacen, yo incluido. El error dice "MySql Tipo De Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; ..." o sea que tienes un error de sintaxis, revisando la consulta del error que devuelve MySQL podrás ver que a tbl_documentos.cedula le falta un valor, algo como tbl_documentos.cedula="prueba".

No pongas directamente el valor de $_POST en la consulta, me imagino que estás haciendo algo como "select * from tbl_documentos where tbl_documentos.cedula=$_POST[palabra]", eso es algo terrible, nunca, nunca, nunca,  debes poner de forma directa una variable post en una consulta a la base de datos, pueden hacerle inyecciones a tú base de datos, debes limpiar o escapar tus variables https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Este es un ejemplo burdo, pero podría ser algo así:

```php
    $palabra = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['palabra']);
    $consulta = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_documentos WHERE tbl_documentos.cedula="'."palabra.'"';
```

Espero te sirvan estos consejos :)

Comment: Añadiría que ```mysqli_real_escape_string``` solo formatea algunos "caracteres peligrosos" y no evita las inyecciones, para ello sería mejor usar sentencias preparadas. Te dejo un enlace para más información sobre como evitar inyecciones SQL: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/53134#53134